# Как сохранить скачанные из репозитория пакеты?

Tags: ubuntu

Не знал в какую тему залить, вообщем вопрос просто как три копейки, если я через `sudo apt-get install` скачиваю репозиторий, то я потом (чтобы не качать его с другого компа) могу его просто скопировать или на флэху скинуть и как это сделать если можно =) Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 3):

Скачанные, т.е. загруженные `apt`, для обновления пакеты по умолчанию находятся в `/var/cache/apt`где их можно с правами root взять для переноса на флэшку и тд и установить вручную на другой машине - способ установки выбирать Вам...в случае если хочется автоматизировать процесс иили стоит вопрос жёсткой экономиии трафика на обновлениях то можно создать для Ubuntu  [локальный репозитарий](http://ubuntu-repository.blogspot.com/2010/10/ubuntu-1004.html), - как один из вариантов можно создать на базе `/var/cache/apt` свой репозитарий написав пару скриптов, но существенный минус в том, что в нем будут только те пакеты  которые были установлены на первой машине ... в любом случае решать и выбирать Вам.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще пакеты сохраняются в `/var/cache/apt/archives`, но это просто пакеты, а не репозиторий. Чтоб его создать, есть утилка `dpkg-scanpackages`.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то пользовалсяa  apt-move. У меня конечно дебиан но, думаю, поможет.

Описание.

> создание и ведение локального пула пакетов Debian
>
> apt-move распределяет пакеты Debian (обычно это пакеты в кэше apt-get(8),находящиеся в каталоге /var/cache/apt/archives) по иерархической структурекаталогов как в официальном архиве Debian.
>
> Периодическое выполнение apt-move позволит иметь частичное зеркало иззагружаемых в кэш пакетов: устаревшие версии пакетов будут удаляться, атакже будет создаваться корректный локальный индексный файл Packages.gz.Инструмент также позволяет собрать частичное или полное локальное зеркалодвоичного дистрибутива Debian (например, это может быть зеркало содержащеетолько пакеты установленные в данной системе).

Answer (score 1):

Сначала в настройках synaptic поставь галку на "сохранять все пакеты в кэше", потом можно создавать локальный реп и с помощью apt-move, и с помощью dpkg-scanpackages, в APTonCD...Собственно, для создания зеркала репозитория есть ещё одна утилита - apt-mirror, но ... хватило бы вам места...

Answer (score 0):

[Репозиторий](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Если на другой машине есть интернет,то копировать программы с другой машины просто не имеет смысла.Что касается обратной стороны,то вы всегда можете записать на флешку нужный вам софт в виде tar,rar,gzip,rpm,а так же deb

Человеческое использование терминала!?Это как?Тут все зависит от ваших знаний,изучите необходимые команды linux(все это можно найти в google)CTRL+ALT+T - быстрое открытие терминала!

Answer (score 0):

Могу добавить лишь, что фраза "Если на другой машине есть интернет, то копировать программы с другой машины просто не имеет смысла" неправильная - копировать есть смысл - закидываете в ту же директорию и ставите пакеты с него - тогда качать не требуется и установка происходит быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю/поправлю: установка проходит не просто "быстро", а намного быстрее, т.к. скорость закачки из Интернета и скорость обмена данными на локальном диске не сравнить!

Answer (score 0):

Для ubuntu существует очень простое приложение aptoncd.